# Sources of inaccuracy for double floating point numbers

Tags: floating-accuracy

Besides the impossibility of representing decimal numbers like 0.1 in a binary base, and, the inaccuracy by design of denormalized floats; is there any other source of inaccuracy when working with double floating-point numbers?

Comment: @RyanVincent beat me to it. My question is whether you are asking this question out of general curiosity, or if it relates to a specific topic you are working on? I'd follow the rule of thumb: if I were working with _discrete_ units of measure (e.g.,  currency or parts per [decimal power]) I would use a decimal type. If I were working with a continuous value, I might use a decimal type.  Then there's a question of whether there are conversions taking place.

Answer (score 2):

Just one strange example of numerical inaccuracy of floats is as follows:

If one converts 9999999.4999999999 to a float and back to a double, the result is given as 10000000, even though that value is obviously closer to 9999999, and even though 9999999.499999999 correctly rounds to 9999999.

I understand that this is a very specific example, but more detailed (and scientific reasoning!) can be found here:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: You mean "converts 9999999.4999999999 to a double then to a float". Also, this is called 'double rounding', so I'm not sure how strange it is, or how it's floating-point specific.